# How to split weekly data to hourly?

Tags: pandas, datetime, data-manipulation

I have to dataframes where I have in one column weekly data and in the other data hourly, such as this:

```
datetime                |   A
------------------------|-------------
06/01/2020  00:00:00    | 130
13/01/2020  00:00:00    |  80
.....................................
21/12/2020  00:00:00    | 234
28/12/2020  00:00:00    | 123
```

and hourly :

```
datetime                |   A
------------------------|-------------
06/01/2020  00:00:00    |   
06/01/2020  01:00:00    |
................................
27/12/2020  22:00:00    |   
27/12/2020  23:00:00    |
```

I would like to fill the hourly data by dividing the weekly data for each respective week by 7*24 (hours in a week). I think that should be relatively straight forward but I am currently struggling a lot while trying to implement it. How would the best way be to implement this?

To clarify I would like something like:

```
datetime                |   A
------------------------|-------------
06/01/2020  00:00:00    |  80/7/24 
06/01/2020  01:00:00    |  80/7/24 
................................
27/12/2020  22:00:00    |  123/7/24 
27/12/2020  23:00:00    |  123/7/24
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, can you put some expected results and a little more information on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
df2 = (df_week.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df_week['datetime']).dt.date)
  .merge(df_hour.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df_hour['datetime']).dt.date), on = 'date', suffixes=['_x', ''])
  .assign(A = lambda x: x.A_x/7/24)[['datetime', 'A']])
df2

               datetime        A
0  06/01/2020  00:00:00  0.77381
1  06/01/2020  01:00:00  0.77381
```

breaking this down:

```
df_week['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_week['datetime']).dt.date
df_hour['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_hour['datetime']).dt.date
df2 = df_week.merge(df_hour, on = 'date', suffixes=['_x', ''])
df_hour['A'] = df2['A_x']/7/24
df_hour

               datetime        A        date
0  06/01/2020  00:00:00  0.77381  2020-06-01
1  06/01/2020  01:00:00  0.77381  2020-06-01
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried to implement it but I think in my case it does not consider the entire week only the specific date. Or do I misunderstand it?

Comment: @fidu13 you already said you have the two dataframes. one with dates and the other hourly. so this deals with the data you already have. not considering anything you do not have